# jQuery UI datepicker - conditionally set a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Total javascript noob here, using the jQuery UI datepicker widget.

If variable selectedDate has a value, I want to add an extra line to the widget parameters. This definitely doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {     
    var parms = {
        dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $("form#my-form").submit();
            },
        }
    if (selectedDate) {
        parms += {defaultDate: selectedDate,}
        }
    $('.pickadate').datepicker(parms);
});
</script>
```

If I remove the IF statement, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: when you use brackets, you're creating an object, which have properties :

```
foo = {bar:'pop'}; // New object, with foo.bar == 'pop'
```

Try to change this :

```
parms += {defaultDate: selectedDate,}
```

For this :

```
parms.defaultDate = selectedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (selectedDate) {        
   parms.defaultDate = selectedDate;
}
```